# Не работает параметр layout_weight

Tags: android-sdk, android, android-layout

Прописываю в `.xml` файле `ActionBar` вот такой код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/actionbar_btn1"
            android:layout_width="10sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button2"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Окно 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/actionbar_btn2"
            android:layout_width="10sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button2"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Окно 2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/actionbar_btn3"
            android:layout_width="10sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button2"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Окно 3" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Но, в результате, выходит вот такое вот чудо, как на фото. На сколько я понял, не работает параметр `layout_weight`. Что делать (всовывать еще один `linear_layout` пробовал)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал исправить код, как сказали в ответах, вышло это:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="40sp"
  android:background="@color/gray" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_btn1"
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button2"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Окно 1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_btn2"
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button2"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Окно 2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_btn3"
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button2"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Окно 3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для начала указывайте относительные размеры в `dp`, а не `sp`. Возможно это не решит вашу проблему, но `sp` используется для другого (указания размера шрифтов)

Comment: На предоставленной вами разметке проблема не воспроизводится (кнопки занимают всю ширину экрана и делят его на три равные части). Добавьте полную разметку всего экрана, а не только лэйаута с кнопками.

Comment: @pavlofff, в смысле "полную разметку всего экрана"?

Comment: Разметку, куда вы помещаете этот контейнер с тремя кнопками. Проблема не в той разметке, которую вы приложили, а в той, что "выше" ее

Comment: @pavlofff, а что стоит выше ActionBar? Я это разметку устанавливаю, как ActionBar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нельзя сочетать жёстко заданную ширину и вес. В этом случае приоритет имеет жестко заданная ширина. Вам надо установить её на `0dip` чтобы вес начал работать. Т.е. заменить `android:layout_width="10sp"` на:

```
android:layout_width="0dip"
```

---

**P.S.**: Также укажите на всякий случай ориентацию корневому `LinearLayout` на горизонтальную.

> android:orientation="horizontal"

Comment: "0dip" я бы на  "dp" изменил

Comment: и sp на dp тоже)

Comment: Юрий, попробовал сделать, как написали Вы. Изменилось не многое... Я обновил вопрос.

Comment: @bukashka101, приведите полностью разметку. И не используйте `sp`. Они используются для указания размера текста. Для ширины/высоты используется `dp`.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, это и есть вся разметка (только ActionaBar`a). dp смогу поставить только вечером, сейчас не дома.

Comment: @bukashka101, @pavlofff верно говорит - нам нужна **вся** ваша разметка, ибо то, что вы привели гарантированно работает так, как нужно. Проблема в том, что выше. И непонятно, почему вы свою разметку `ActionBar`-ом называете... Вы её пытаетесь в него поместить?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, даже, я ее ставлю, как ActionBar.

Comment: Скорее всего вам не надо так делать... Скорее всего вам нужны табы, а акшнбар вообще не нужен.

Comment: Я накладываю ActionBar поверх этой разметки - http://pastebin.com/RgjctADj, с вот этим вот Jаva кодом — http://pastebin.com/RndpStKN